# Normalize with respect to weight percent contribution

Tags: statistics

I am looking for some mathematical solution to calculate normalize score for an Index comprising multiple stock information.

The Index has 5 companies stock information and each company has different weight contribution adding to 100%.

```
Example: 
Company Wt
ABC     25%
DEF     30%
GHI     15%
JKL     5%
MNO     25%
```

Now I am tracking each company stock prices every day and calculating the change % for it.

```
Example:
Company Price (02/11/2019)  Price (02/12/2019)  Price change    % change
ABC        2                   2.1                0.1        5.00%
DEF        3                   3.2                0.2        6.67%
GHI        5                   6                  1         20.00%
JKL        8                   9.5                1.5       18.75%
MNO        4                   3.5               -0.5      -12.50%
```

If we plot the above result, it will show that companies GHI and JKL has largest change [link to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Phc.jpg) however,
I am trying to normalize (between 0 and 1) the above results with respect to their weight contributions and plot with the above result to show the trend with respect to wt contribution.

I am looking for some calculations and method which I can use.
Grateful for any help.
Regards
KR

Comment: The contribution of MNO must be negative. Thus it cannot be between 0 and 1. Maybe the contributions can be normalized so that the contributions are between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks callculus for your suggestion. I agree it will vary between -1 and +1. Any statistical or mathematical solution to solve the problem.